# Asked to save browser by Facebook

Tags: facebook

I cannot log in my Facebook account anymore. This is what I get:

> Remember Browser
>
> Because you have Login Notifications enabled, you will receive a notification when you log in from a new browser. Please save this browser if you use it often.
>
> Save Browser
>
> Don't Save

I get stuck there. Clicking on "people" only gives a very limited choice for common names. Facebook seems to recognize me but I cannot access my security setting either. Facebook's help department does not answer. What can I do now?

Comment: Just click "Save Browser", it should work.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Regardless of what I select, clicking "Next" returns to the same page. :(

Answer (score 1):

just go to the

> setting>security>Login Approvals

and then un-check

> Require a security code to access my account from unknown browsers

then click save settings

Answer (score 0):

After you click on "Next" a few times, a link saying something like "Do you see this often?" should appear on the page. Click the link. In the popup that appears, click on "Deactivate" to deactivate login notifications. Click logout and login again. This time, you should go straight to your timeline.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have enabled security check. If Facebook does not recognise the browser from where you login, it asks to save it or not. You can save the browser so that when you login from the same browser on same machine it won't ask you for the confirmation.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually facebook thinks that, someone tried to access your account. Therefore it is locked it down.

### This Problem occurs due to following reason:

1. If you have clicked "Save Browser" and after logout someone tries to log-in.
2. Or you have tried to access Facebook on someone's computer who clicked that "Save browser" button.
3. Or some one really tried to hack your account.

### Solution:

1. Try to recognise the photos of your friends.
2. In case you added some random people, or someone really tagged in you a vague photo, Get a friend, ask him to go to your profile and check that photo. This will give you a guaranteed answer.